# Exibir tempo de execução de uma aplicação [C#]

Tags: c#, thread, time

Gostaria de ajuda quanto a um processo que necessito fazer: A ideia é criar uma label informativa que conterá o tanto de horas, minutos e segundos que minha aplicação está funcionando. O tempo começa a ser contado desde que o form abrir.

Não sei exatamente como iniciar. Eu estava pesquisando e cheguei até o método `Stopwatch`, porém não sei se é o mais adequado. Alguém poderia me auxiliar sobre como fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma ideia seria criar um `Datetime` quando inicia o form, e dentro do evento `Tick` de um `timer`, por exemplo com o `Interval` a 1000 (1 segundo), fazer a subtracção desse DateTime com o DateTime actual (retorna um TimeSpan).

ex:

```
private DateTime dataInicio = DateTime.Now;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - dataInicio;
    this.label1.Text = span.ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");
}
```

Caso não queira mostar o dias, pode retirar `dd\.`, mas passado um dia as horas ficam a `0` e não `24`... terá arranjar um jeito, por exemplo usando a propriedade `TotalHours`.

ex:

```
this.label1.Text = ((int)span.TotalHours).ToString() + ":" + span.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
```